# Strange `pwd` output from perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix, ubuntu, pwd

I have a very short tutorial perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "The date is ",`date`;
print "The date is `date`",".\n";
$directory=`pwd`;
print "\nThe current directory is $directory.";
```

and the output:

```
The date is Sat Jul  2 17:04:58 PDT 2011
The date is `date`.

The current directory is total 20
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yan yan 433 2011-07-02 15:58 36
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yan yan 313 2011-07-02 16:29 43
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yan yan 116 2011-07-02 16:51 45
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yan yan 149 2011-07-02 16:53 46
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yan yan 145 2011-07-02 17:02 47
```

But if I just run pwd I got:

```
yan@ubuntu:~/bin/blackperl$ pwd
/home/yan/bin/blackperl
```

Any logical explanation to the mystery here? thanks a lot!

Comment: When I run your script, the last line of output is: `The current directory is /home/user/asdf` So I don't know. I'm guessing something in your environment may be skewing the results.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 9.10.  it seems outputing "ls -l", but since "pwd" works fine under the shell... weird

Comment: Could it be that your perl is using another shell for the `` calls than you are using for the comparison, thus having other settings? What does `print `type pwd`; ` print in perl? (with backquotes inside)?

Comment: In Ubuntu, the default shell for script execution is `dash`, while the default shell for user interaction is `bash`. I suppose Perl will call the first one, and you have some alias defined in your dash initialization scripts.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann, Perl uses `/bin/sh` when it needs a shell, although it doesn't use a shell at all in this case.

Comment: @cpp initiator, From your prompt, is the output of `\pwd` the same as that of `pwd`?

Comment: What is the output of `perl -e 'print qx(type pwd)'` ? `perl -e 'print qx(which pwd)` ?

Comment: @ikegami: I thought that text within `` will be [executed by the system's shell](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators). Or would `pwd` be special-cased here?  (`/bin/sh` is `dash` on Ubuntu systems.)

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann , Notice the word "possibly" in the documentation you linked. The behaviour is detailed in [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for `system`: the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing (this is `/bin/sh -c` on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms).

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann, note that the behaviour of Perl on Windows differs from the documentation. It may use a shell even for commands with no shell characters. e.g. `system('dir')` should fail, but doesn't. `system({ 'dir' } 'dir')` does fail as it should, though.

Comment: @ikegami: Ah, I'm starting to understand. `perl -e qx(pwd)` might execute `/bin/pwd` (or whatever is found in the path) instead of the shell buildin. And if the first one does strange things while the ones build in the shells are nice, we could get the observed behaviour.

Comment: @ikegami: Can we condense this result in an answer? I could write it, but as it is mainly your input here, you should get the honor to be the author, if you want. (I would upvote it.)

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann, I don't have an answer. I have no idea what's causing the OP's problem. I was just pointing out that it's unlikely to be due to an alias.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes. It is more likely due to a wrong `pwd` binary in the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A possible explanation for the mystery**:

You have some program named `pwd` in the command search path (i.e. in one of the directories named by the PATH environment variable) which does these strange things. When executing `pwd` in your interactive shell (bash) or in a shell script (dash), you get the buildin command `pwd`, which prints the current working directory, as it should.

On the other hand, in your Perl source line

```
$directory=`pwd`;
```

Perl does not invoke the system's shell by using the C `system()` function, but instead directly executes the `pwd` command in the path (using the [`execvp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) call in a forked process), since the command looks simple enough (a *simple command*, in bash terminology). If this `pwd` binary is not the usual `/bin/pwd` binary (which also simply prints the current directory), but instead does something like `ls -l`, we get the observed behaviour.

**The real solution** would be to fix your PATH and/or remove the bogus `pwd` binary. Use `which pwd` to find out where it is (or `type -a pwd` on bash).

**A solution from the Perl side** would be to force a shell call:

```
$directory=`pwd;`;
```

This forces Perl to call the shell instead of directly executing the program. (More generally, any *shell metacharacter* has this effect. This is described only for Perl's [system function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), not for the [quote-execute operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%60STRING%60).)

In this case Perl would invoke `/bin/sh`, which in Ubuntu (at least in current versions, I'm not sure about your 9.10) is `dash` (Debian Almquist Shell) instead of `bash` (GNU's Bourne Again Shell). Dash is a much simpler (and faster) `sh` implementation than bash, but for things like `pwd` there should be no difference (it is a buildin in my dash, too), as long as you have no aliases or shell functions defined in one shell and not the other.

Of course, **a better solution** would be to use Perl's [Cwd](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) module, as [recommended in the answer by toolic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560301/strange-pwd-output-from-perl/6560412#6560412).

---

*Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for explaining the semantics of the backticks operator to me in the comments to the question.*

Comment: wow, you're incredible! You are like Sherlock Holmes seeing the crime scene without being there! I did find an executable file named pwd in a $PATH folder! I didn't even remember it, but after reading your reply, I checked... and found the missing clue! Thank you very much and really appreciate your insightful answer!

Comment: I'm glad to see tha I guessed right here. After the clarification from ikegami about the workings of the qx-operator there couldn't really be another reason.

Answer (score 7):

I can't exlpain the mystery either, but you could try to use the Perl Core module [Cwd](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) instead of the `pwd` command:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Cwd;
my $dir = getcwd();
print "$dir\n";
```

One advantage is that `Cwd` is more portable than `pwd`.

See also: [UNIX 'command' equivalents in Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=627015)

Answer (score 3):

It works fine here, too (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server).  I have no idea as to why `$directory` would spit out the output of `ls`.

ETA:  Run this from the command line:

`perl -e 'print "$ENV{PWD}\n";'`

and tell me what the output is.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me too.  I'm wondering if it might have something to do with a shell alias or shell function.  You can alias a command to another command in bash like this:

```
doug@supermicro:~$ alias pwd='ls -la'
```

Here's more on alias: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29

Although I can't think why the shell command run by the Perl program would have access to a different set of aliases from the set you have access to.

Are you running this program from the command line or are you running it through another process?  (such as a CGI script which is run by the Apache user account)

You can also define shell functions with the same names as external commands and which are run instead of the external commands, but this doesn't explain why you get normal output directly from the command line.

Comment: Perl doesn't use a shell for `qx{pwd}`. Try: `alias pwd='ls -la'`, then `pwd`, then `perl -e'print qx{pwd}'` (`qx{}` and backticks are teh same thing, but backticks are clashing with SO's markup.)